# AngularJS Json Array

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

I have the following JSON:

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac"),
            "result" : {
                    "full" : {
                            "Array1" : [
                                    "mytext1",
                                    "mytext2"
                            ],
                            "Array2" : [
                                    "mytext3",
                                    "mytext3"
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
```

To get everything: **OK**

```
console.log("response ", response);
```

To get the _id: **OK**

```
console.log("_id ", response._id);
```

**But** I can't access to mytext1, mytext2, ...

How I can proceed with angularjs?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `response.result.full.Array1[0]`, `response.result.full.Array1[1]`, `response.result.full.Array2[0]`, `response.result.full.Array2[1]`

Comment: why is this tagged with angular? have you tried `console.log(response.result.full.Array1[1]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response` is an object. `result` is an object. `full` is an object. `Array1` and `Array2` are, obviously enough, arrays.

For mytext1:

```
response.result.full.Array1[0]
```

For mytext2:

```
response.result.full.Array1[1]
```

For mytext3:

```
response.result.full.Array2[0]
```

For mytext4:

```
response.result.full.Array2[1]
```

If you want to log everything in the array, use a simple `for...loop`:

```
var arr = response.result.full.Array1;
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know necessary the size of the array. How I can make sure I display everything in the array (depending on the size)?

Comment: response.result.full.Array1[0] ... return undefined

Comment: Oh yes, you're right ! My db was empty :( Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = {
        "_id" : "542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac",
        "result" : {
                "full" : {
                        "Array1" : [
                                "mytext1",
                                "mytext2"
                        ],
                        "Array2" : [
                                "mytext3",
                                "mytext3"
                        ]
                }
        }
};

//The next for iterates over the names Array1, Array2 (and if you have more)
for(var array in q.result.full)
{
    //This for iterates over the elements of each array
    for(i = 0; i < q.result.full[array].length; i++)
    {
        console.log(q.result.full[array][i]);
    }
}
```